# what controls the outbound ring tone on LG Optimus F7 all i get is tones instead of ring tone

Tags: ringtone

When i make a call all i here is a tone every few seconds just like its ringing but tones instead and the call goes thru. I can not find any setting that changes the out going ring tone.

Answer (score 0):

The technical term for what you are describing is the ringback tone, and it is in general controlled by your carrier, or the far end carrier. It has nothing to do with your device.